# Infinite prisoners with hats -- is choice really needed?

Tags: set-theory, recreational-mathematics, axiom-of-choice

The problem is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoners_and_hats_puzzle#Countably_Infinite-Hat_Variant_without_Hearing) (recently asked about [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032928/prisoners-problem)):

> A countably infinite number of prisoners, each with an unknown and randomly assigned red or blue hat line up single file line. Each prisoner faces away from the beginning of the line, and each prisoner can see all the hats in front of him, and none of the hats behind. Starting from the beginning of the line, each prisoner must correctly identify the color of his hat or he is killed on the spot. The prisoners have a chance to meet and confer beforehand, but once in line, no prisoner can hear what the other prisoners say. The question is, is there a way to ensure that only finitely many prisoners are killed?

The standard solution depends on the Axiom of Choice, as discussed in [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340725/why-does-the-infinite-prisoners-and-hats-puzzle-require-the-axiom-of-choice).

However, the previous question only explains that *that* particular strategy requires the Axiom of Choice. It still seems at least conceivable that there could be a completely different strategy that works and doesn't need Choice.

**Thus:** Is it known to be consistent with ZF that there is no strategy for the prisoners?

(Bonus question: If "yes", then is this also true in the variant where the prisoners can hear the answers of lower-numbered prisoners?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After working out a little bit of math, I suddenly remembered that this was asked, in some variation, on MathOverflow. Thankfully, Nate Eldredge posted [an answer to this question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/184444/7206) which had just the right reference.

> Hardin, Christopher S.; Taylor, Alan D. **[An introduction to infinite hat problems](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF03038092)**. *Math. Intelligencer* **30** (2008), no. 4, 20–25. [MR2501394](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2501394).

In this paper the authors show that it is consistent with $\sf ZF+DC+BP$ (where $\sf BP$ is the axiom stating that every set of reals has the Baire property) that there is no winning strategy. Of course this theory is equiconsistent with $\sf ZFC$ (as shown by Shelah), and follows from $\sf AD$ as well it holds in Solovay's model.

Additional information can surely be found in their book (mentioned in the comments of Nate's answer by Francois Dorais), whose subtitle is "A study of generalized hat problems"

> *Christopher S. Hardin and Alan D. Taylor*, [**The mathematics of coordinated inference**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-01333-6), ISBN: 978-3-319-01332-9; 978-3-319-01333-6.

This might also seem interesting,

> Hardin, Christopher S.; Taylor, Alan D. **[Minimal predictors in hat problems](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/fm208-3-4)**. *Fund. Math.* **208** (2010), no. 3, 273–285. [MR2650985](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2650985).

Comment: Incredible. That MO thread is just 5 weeks old. When I remembered it, it felt as if it is nearly a year old. I'd say that time flies when you do a lot. But I didn't do all that much in these five weeks! Where did time go? :(

Comment: Isn't time actually *failing* to fly in this case?

Comment: @Kevin: Well, time is like a snail that can fly very fast sometimes, or crawl very slowly. So if it didn't fly, it had to crawl. But it didn't crawl. I don't remember doing anything in this past month, other than procrastinating writing the fine details of something new. In fact, I'm still procrastinating that! Just look at this comment! :-)

Comment: I'll take your word for it, since the papers are paywalled.

Comment: @Henning: Send me an email, I'll see what I can do it when I wake up.

Comment: @Asaf: Naw, prolly wouldn't be able to follow it anyway. Just railing a bit against Springer who thought satisfying this idle curiosity would be worth 35 euro to someone.

Comment: @Asaf: Just wait: the day will come when things that you remember as having happened just a few years earlier are ancient history to your students and young colleagues!

Comment: @Brian: My students don't know who Columbo was. My guess is that the phrase "I am not a number, I am a free man!" will mean nothing to them as well.

Comment: (ehm... excuse me, but I am lost. After perusing Wikipedia, I think that DC is the Axiom of Dependent Choice and AD the Axiom of Determinacy, but I am not certain. The question is also labeled "recreational mathematicatics": ZF and ZFC are standard jargon, other abbreviation not.

Comment: @mau: I don't follow your comment. $\sf DC$ is a very standard jargon when it comes to the axiom of choice related questions, and for what it's worth, $\sf AD$ is pretty standard too.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: were the question just labeled "set theory", I would never have opened it :-) I stumbled about it because I am subscribed to "recreational mathematics" tag. I understand these abbreviations are fairly standard jargon for people doing set theory, but for other people, even if with a mathematical background, they are not; of course I had to search elsewhere what those axioms say (and that's no problem), but I had also to guess their name...

Comment: @mau: Well, searching for `"axiom of choice" DC` gave as the first result the Wiki page for dependent choice; similarly with `AD` instead gave the axiom of determinacy Wiki result on the second place, but the first place was the axiom of choice itself with the excerpt that says "Axiom of Determinacy, or AD". But I hear what you're saying and I'll try to take that into account in the future.

Comment: Their book (or at least some draft version?) is available here (no paywall): http://qcpages.qc.cuny.edu/~rmiller/abstracts/Hardin-Taylor.pdf

Comment: @Henning: See Hans' comment. Thank you very much Hans!

Comment: Thanks, @Hans. -- Asaf, I recognise the The Prisoner quote, but that is a matter of popcultural osmosis rather than being old enough to have seen it broadcast ...

Comment: @Henning: Of course I don't expect them to know about The Prisoner (despite the fact it is still the best TV show ever made), but last year only two were watching True Detective, if you want to talk about contemporary pop culture. And they are not at all versed in good pop culture. It's horrible too, since I make plenty of references to TV and movies as I go along (in real life too). I keep calling them Philistines, but they don't know what I mean either (which shows lack of Bob Dylan familiarity, because that's where I learned it)... :-P